# HTML5 DatePicker Custom Color of Date using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, colors, datepicker

Using Google Chrome

Example Code:

```
<input id='dateval' type='date'>
```

Is it possible to change only some of the date color when the datepicker is clicked?

I want Date of 25-07-2015 and 27-07-2015 to be green background when I click the datepicker (the table of datepicker)

Comment: Input type date isn't supported by all browsers in use. Even where it is, it's not that configurable. If you're looking for a javascript solution, you'll need to show what you've tried.

Comment: I dont even know how to configure it using javascript, cause i cannot inspect the element of that datepicker table, so i dont know how

Comment: You could try searching for [*javascript date picker*](https://www.google.com.au/#q=javascript+date+picker).

Comment: I think that it is only the way too..thanks @RobG